# select named field in ef core select statement which uses generics

Tags: c#, linq, generics, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I have the method below which will insert new records into my database

```
public static async Task SaveDataToEntitySetAsync<TEntity>(DbContext context,List<TEntity> list) 
    where TEntity : class
{
    if(list.Any() == false)
        return;
    
     var dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
     var existingData = await dbSet.Select(x=>x.Id).ToListAsync();
     list.RemoveAll(x => existingData.Contains(x.Id));
     await dbSet.AddRangeAsync(list);
}
```

The logic above is what I am trying to do if I wasnt using generics

How can I convert this into a syntax which will work for generics?  This syntax wont work in a generic context as .Id is not valid

I am using EF Core so when a record is added to a table, EF core is automatically adding records into the associated foreign key tables

The problem with this approach is that I call this method for each table in my context.

So lets say a customer in the UK is added.  This is fine, the customer gets added, and the Country UK is added (assuming its not already there)

I also have an extract of all the countries which I save to the database.  Obviously this will now break because UK has already been saved

Therefore I am trying to remove any items from my countries list which are already in the database

All of my entities come off of a BaseEntity (which is where Id is defined) but Im not sure how to make use of that fact

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your entities already inherit from the same base class which has the `Id` property, you can just constrain your generic type to that:

```
where TEntity : BaseEntity
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a `Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>> keyExtractor` lambda expression like `x => x.Id`:

```
public static async Task SaveDataToEntitySetAsync<TEntity, TKey>(DbContext context, List<TEntity> list, Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>> keyExtractor)
    where TEntity : class
{
    if (list.Any() == false)
        return;

    var dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    var existingData = await dbSet.Select(keyExtractor).ToListAsync();

    Func<TEntity, TKey> keyExtractorCompiled = keyExtractor.Compile();
    list.RemoveAll(x => existingData.Contains(keyExtractorCompiled(x)));

    await dbSet.AddRangeAsync(list);
}
```

and then:

```
await SaveDataToEntitySetAsync(..., x => x.Id);
```